# Is there a way to perform a mobile detect that EXACTLY matches Facebook's mobile detect?

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-apps

I'm building a hybrid Facebook app: desktop users will be directed to a [Page Tab](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/), while mobile users will be directed to a [Mobile Web App](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/web/build/).

I need to figure out a **fast, accurate way** to detect the user's device and perform the appropriate redirect – ideally something not too complex. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…Yes! It can absolutely be done.

Facebook automatically redirects mobile users attempting to access a Canvas App (`apps.facebook.com/your_app`) to its Mobile Web App equivalent.

So, just set up a server-side redirect to `apps.facebook.com/your_app`, and set up a client-side redirect from the Canvas App to the Page Tab.

Facebook will redirect mobile users to your Mobile Web App; desktop users will land on your Canvas App, which will immediately redirect them to your Page Tab.

The server-side redirect looks like this, in PHP:

```php
<?php
header('Location: http://apps.facebook.com/your_app', TRUE, 302);
exit;
```

The client-side redirect looks like this, in JavaScript:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">window.top.location.href = "http://yoururl.com/desktop/";</script>
```

This is a reliable solution, much better than trying to match user agents. Your list of user agents might be different from Facebook's; and indeed, Facebook is very inconsistent with how it performs mobile redirects.